# Asp.net grid view template fields data persist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a grid view which contains 4 template fields, each containing a text box.

Now I have bound these template fields with a datasource. When I as a user type in some data in the text box and click on save button (a button which is not a part of gridview but an individual one in the webform), I am not able to get the values in the click event handler in the code behind file. Please help me.

ASPX file

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col1"> 
    <ControlStyle Height="25px" Width="60px" />
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[col1]") %>'>   
            </asp:TextBox>                 
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col2">  
  <ControlStyle Height="25px" Width="60px" />
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("[col2]") %>'>  
      </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col3"> 
  <ControlStyle Height="25px" Width="60px" />
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("[col3]") %>'>
      </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col4"> 
  <ControlStyle Height="25px" Width="60px" />
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt4" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("[col4]") %>'>
      </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>       
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind file

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvEdit.Rows)
    {
            string a = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("col1")).Text;
                 //above line gives a null value
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to add your HTML as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the `GridViewRowCollection`, and then for each row, find the control by the `Id` you gave it in the markup. For example:

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvEdit.Rows)
    {
        var txt1 = row.FindControl("txt1") as TextBox;
        var txt2 = row.FindControl("txt2") as TextBox;
        var txt3 = row.FindControl("txt3") as TextBox;
        var txt4 = row.FindControl("txt4") as TextBox;

        // access the Text property of each, e.g. txt1.Text
    }
}
```

**Update:** Make sure that when you do the data source binding, it only happens on the initial load and not subsequent postbacks, otherwise your changes will be reset each time.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = // data source
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nop. It doesnt not work. if i provide the values from a datasource , the same value returns, but if i modify dat in the text box (as a user), it returns  data in the datasource only

Comment: @user3107338 I haven't seen the data binding logic but make sure it only happens on initial load. See updated answer.

Comment: wow. forgot to put that post back condition. Thanks a lottttttt for suggesting.